# Hive: Select rows with max value from a column

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I want to select all rows for which the timestamp column has the maximum value.
The data looks like this:

```
A      B      timestamp
john   smith   2018
bob    dylan   2018
adam   levine  2017
bob    dylan   2017
```

The result should be:

```
A      B      timestamp
john   smith   2018
bob    dylan   2018
```

With Impala, the following SQL Query works:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp=(SELECT Max(timestamp) from table)

But with Hive, the SQL Query doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Please always include the error message.

Try with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT Max(timestamp) from table)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. The problem was not Hive, but the Cloudera Frontend Hue, which threw errors, when I typed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rank :

```
SELECT
    D.A
    ,D.B
    ,D.timestamp
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            A
            ,B
            ,timestamp
            ,RANK(timestamp) over ( order by timestamp DESC ) as rank_
        FROM 
            TABLE
    ) D 
WHERE
    D.rank_=1
```